# Want to create a action filter to force Url to be using SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, action-filter

I want to create a action filter that will check the url, and if its not using Ssl, redirect to the same page but with SSL.

What is the best way of doing this?

Should I just check the RawUrl, and scan the string for https, and if its not there then do:

```
context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.RawUrl.Replace("http:", "https:"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is one (in MVC 2, at least): `RequireSsl`. I think it may be in futures in MVC 1, but I haven't used MVC 1 in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, it's now the `System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute`.

I'm on MVC 2.